# Swipeable tabs and programmatically adding them

Tags: android

At the moment, I have a ListView filled with data and when an item is selected, a new activity is opened.

I want to change this so that when an item is selected, a new tab should be added with a certain title and the activity showed underneath that tab, I also want the user to be able to swipe between tabs.

After looking on the android development website, I found https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html#scrollable which shows an example of the Play Store app and the scrollable tabs they have there. However, I cannot find any examples of this would be set up and also I could programmatically add tabs.

Comment: Update SDK and the ADB plugin, then create a new Android project and you will see a window where you can select a template. Choose Tabs+Swype and you will have a sample application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TheNewBoston](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=86) If you are lost, you may want to go a few tutorials back to 84 in this [list](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6)
On the side note, have you consider fragments and a viewpager?